# Android Maps error "Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager'"

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm doing a simple app with maps, it worked fine at first but suddenly the map isn't displayed anymore and these errors are displayed in the logcat:

```
06-06 20:53:37.007  31809-31809/com.example.veuge.maps E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
06-06 20:53:38.849  31809-31809/com.example.veuge.maps E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.hg.a
```

I've tried everything: I reviewed the API key, I reset the targetSdkPermission and updated the Google Play Services. I just don't know what else to do. Help please

Comment: What api version are you targeting? It needs to be api level 19 or higher.

Comment: I set the api level to 19 and the error persists

Comment: give it a view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342684/getting-error-could-not-find-class-android-app-appopsmanager-referenced-from?lq=1

Comment: The solution for this problem is solved at this stackoverflow post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033800/noclassdeffounderror-below-sdk-21

Answer (score 0):

After spending couple of days to solve this strange problem, Finally found the cause of the crash. Although the error persists, program runs without any problem now.

Documents states it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

The solution for this problem is solved at [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033800/noclassdeffounderror-below-sdk-21)