# React-native android project with many error: Could not find class 'android.XXX'

Tags: android, react-native, versioning

I have a react-native project which should support minimum SDK version of 16 and is androidX but I get these errors using android studio logcat:

```
 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method androidx.core.os.UserManagerCompat.isUserUnlocked
 12-21 16:19:25.003 12695-12695/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.wrappers.PackageManagerWrapper.zzb
 12-21 16:19:25.153 12695-12719/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method androidx.core.app.AppOpsManagerCompat.noteOp
 12-21 16:19:25.153 12695-12719/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method androidx.core.app.AppOpsManagerCompat.noteOpNoThrow
 12-21 16:19:25.153 12695-12719/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method androidx.core.app.AppOpsManagerCompat.noteProxyOp
 12-21 16:19:25.153 12695-12719/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method androidx.core.app.AppOpsManagerCompat.noteProxyOpNoThrow
 12-21 16:19:25.213 12695-12695/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.crashlytics.android.ndk.CrashlyticsNdk', referenced from method com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider.createCrashlyticsKits
 12-21 16:19:25.464 12695-12735/com.myProject.demo E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.isRestrictedUserProfile
 12-21 16:19:25.884 12695-12735/com.myProject.demo E/Fabric: Settings request failed.
 12-21 16:19:25.894 12695-12736/com.myProject.demo E/Answers: Failed to retrieve settings
```

I searched a lot and the only related thing I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033800/noclassdeffounderror-below-sdk-21), which is not solving my problem.

I don't know if this helps or not these are dependencies in my app/build.gradle. Maybe one of these or not compatible with API version 16

```
// Firebase dependencies
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.4"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.3'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0"
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

// Android X
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

the UserManager is added in SDK version of 17, so it can not find it. you can see this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager) for details.

if you want to use it, you have to in the android native add support library. the `com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1` has it.

if you have added the androidX library, you should change the class to `UserManagerCompat`. for details, you can go into this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/os/UserManagerCompat)
it is located in `androidX.core`. add the following at `android/app/build.gradle`

```
def core_role_version = "1.0.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.core:core-role:$core_role_version"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using UserManager and I don't know which of my libraries is using it. Do you mean I need to add " com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1"? where?

Comment: I tried that but this is not working with react-native-screens, is there any other version to support userManager?

Comment: I do have them and no difference!

Comment: @Niloufar, it is used in `com.google.android.gms`. not react-native-screen

Comment: Thanks Lenoarod I tried this solution as well. but still same errors and not running on android 4.1