# suddenly getting dalvik error like unable to resolve virtual method for

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, dalvik

after updating suddenly i am getting this type of error

```
 unable to resolve virtual method 741: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)
 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.AppOpsManager.checkPackage, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzb
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
 Could not find method android.app.Activity.stopLockTask, referenced
 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.View.startNestedScroll, 
 nable to resolve virtual method 21303: Landroid/widget/Button;.getAccessibilityClassName ()Ljava/lang/CharSequence;
VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18006: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.unScrap ()V
```

other errors are also present but most of the unable to resolve virtual method

app is not crashing but why this type of error coming

is this issue or its fine ?

Edit 
   error are
       RecyclerView related like RecyclerViewHolder.access$super

```
  DexOpt: illegal method access (call     
 Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.doReallyStop
 DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.doReallyStop
could not find method android.app.Activity.getContentTransitionManager,
```

Comment: `after updating` updating what?

Comment: _other errors are also present_   please add these too, perhaps they are all related.

Comment: Seems to be something that you fix with clean/rebuild

Comment: gradle:2.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services8.4.0

Comment: i have done lot of timeclean rebuild no luck

Comment: I am also facing this issue after upgrading Android studio to 2.0, though app not crashes.

Comment: yes  after upgrading Android studio to 2.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342684/getting-error-could-not-find-class-android-app-appopsmanager-referenced-from)

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour.

If, for example, you compile targeting API 20 but are running this on an API 15 device, there will be a few methods and classes missing. That's what these logs are warning you.

If you are careful not to call newer API methods on older versions (Android studio would warn you about that and if use the support library they take care of those things) you will be fine.

Source: [How to resolve this error VFY: unable to resolve virtual method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874821/how-to-resolve-this-error-vfy-unable-to-resolve-virtual-method)

Or better yet in this bug report taken from that answer

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198567

Answer (score 0):

There are many similar [questions already asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Getting%20error%3A%20Could%20not%20find%20class%20android.app.AppOpsManager%20%20[android]). However there is no specific solution for these error logs. I have also faced such error messages in `Logcat` after upgrading to **Android Studio:2.0**, although App is not crashing.

You can [try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31422569/2571277) if it solves your problem. Still as far as your app is not crashing you can ignore them. Latest version of Android studio may has something for these logs. Hope for quick update.