# Could not find class 'android.app.Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener'

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I am using android studio 2.1. When I run the app i am getting this type of errors.

```
04-29 10:47:50.870 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-29 10:47:50.910 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/InstantRun: Could not find slices in APK; aborting.
04-29 10:47:50.920 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.applications.AFatalApp.access$super
04-29 10:47:50.920 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.applications.AFatalApp.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.010 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
04-29 10:47:51.010 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache
04-29 10:47:51.080 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.SplashActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.080 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.SplashActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.080 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.SplashActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.080 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.SplashActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.090 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.SplashActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.100 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.SplashActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.100 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.SplashActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.100 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.TransitionManager', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.SplashActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.100 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.SplashActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.110 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.SplashActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.110 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.SplashActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.110 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.SplashActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.130 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.global.AFatalActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.130 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.global.AFatalActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.130 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.global.AFatalActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.130 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.global.AFatalActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.130 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.global.AFatalActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.130 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.global.AFatalActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.130 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.global.AFatalActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.130 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.TransitionManager', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.global.AFatalActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.130 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.global.AFatalActivity.access$super
 04-29 10:47:51.140 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.global.AFatalActivity.access$super
 04-29 10:47:51.150 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.global.AFatalActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.150 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method  com.demo.a_fatal.global.AFatalActivity.access$super
04-29 10:47:51.160 20286-20286/com.demo.a_fatal E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.demo.a_fatal.dialog.ProgressDialog.access$super
```

How can i solved this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342684/getting-error-could-not-find-class-android-app-appopsmanager-referenced-from

Answer (score 2):

[see this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198567).
I also came across this problem, the way to solve it is as follows:
first disable the "InstantRun" function, then click "Invalidate Cache/Restart" in "File" Menu, uninstall the apk in phone or emulator is ok before rebuilding it. Then there are no errors like that. In fact, these errors don't make any difference to the apk.

Answer (score 0):

You have this issue because you are trying to method that is available only from API level 21.The issue is because of Change to compileSdkVersion 22 & update the build.gradle to 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'